# UWP How to create user control that hosts content?

Tags: c#, uwp, controltemplate

I am getting really frustrated in trying to achieve a very trivial thing (or at least, something what I would expect should be trivial...)

I have a requirement where a toggle button should be customized, for which I need to make a user control which hosts the toggle button, and host the content which is described in that user control. I made a small mini app to demonstrate the "requirement".

```
<local:MyUserControl1>
    <TextBlock>Just an example</TextBlock>
</local:MyUserControl1>
```

The `MyUserControl1` looks as follows:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App2.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Name="Bla" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Ellipse Width="300" Height="300" Fill="Blue"/>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=Bla, Path=MainContent}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <ToggleButton/>
</UserControl>
```

Code behind:

```
    public static DependencyProperty MainContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MainContent",
        typeof(object),
        typeof(MyUserControl1),
        null);

    public object MainContent
    {
        get => GetValue(MainContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(MainContentProperty, value);
    }
```

When I run the app, the text is shown, but the style / togglebutton is ignored / not applied / whatever.

[image]

The visual tree confirms that I do something wrong:

[image]

I have viewed many many other related SO Q&As, but I still have no idea how to get this working the way I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You code should be working, except that there are no lines shown where [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.contentpropertyattribute) should be. Could you make sure that `MyUserControl1` has it's content property identified and see if that helps.

```
[ContentProperty(Name = "MainContent")]
public sealed partial class MyUserControl1 : UserControl
...
```

---

#### Update

There is full code below that was tested with Win 10 Pro 1803, build 17134, NETCore 6.2.2.

Note that you can define control template either in `UserControl.Resources` or external resources to separate it from the "main" UI layout or keep it in `ToggleButton.Template` for a few less lines of XAML.

#### UserControlWithContent.xaml

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SmallTests2018.UserControlWithContent"
    x:Name="Self"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Width="300" Height="300" Fill="Blue"/>
                    <ContentPresenter
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        Content="{Binding MainContent, ElementName=Self, FallbackValue='{}{ content }'}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ToggleButton.Template>
    </ToggleButton>
</UserControl>
```

#### UserControlWithContent.xaml.cs

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup;

namespace SmallTests2018
{
    [ContentProperty(Name = "MainContent")]
    public sealed partial class UserControlWithContent : UserControl
    {
        public UserControlWithContent()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static DependencyProperty MainContentProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MainContent", typeof(object), typeof(UserControlWithContent), null);

        public object MainContent
        {
            get => GetValue(MainContentProperty);
            set => SetValue(MainContentProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

#### UserControlWithContentPage.xaml

```
<Page
    x:Class="SmallTests2018.UserControlWithContentPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SmallTests2018"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Viewbox>
        <local:UserControlWithContent>
            <TextBlock FontSize="32" Foreground="Yellow">Just an example</TextBlock>
        </local:UserControlWithContent>
    </Viewbox>
</Page>
```

#### Page XAML designer screenshot

[image]

Comment: Well, since approach based on your code worked for me, I'm going to post the full code here, just in case it may help someone.

Comment: Hah! Copied bit by bit and that does work on my PC as well. The approach I used with a style doesn't seem to work then. Your way I also don't have to (/are not allowed to) define the content in main page with `<UserControl.MainContent>` tags. In any event, this does the job nicely! Thx, i will use it another time then :)